# Symfony check url contains query

Tags: php, symfony

My Url will look like

mysite.com/?authenticated=1#/
or
mysite.com/?anonymous=1#/

I am trying to check if Url is authenticated or anonymous.

```
$auth = $request->query->get('authenticated');
$anon = $request->query->get('anonymous');
if ($auth) {
  print "authorised";
  }  
elseif ($anon) {
  print "anonymous"; 
  }
else {
  print "unknown";
}
```

Im using symfony, whether I visit mysite.com/?authenticated=1#/ or mysite.com/?anonymous=1#/ or mysite.com/something I always get unknown.

How can I check whether the query contains authenticated or anonymous?

Thanks

Comment: I’m seeing fragments with path-like things (`#/`), are you doing some JS-based routing, too?

Comment: hi @ChrisHaas yes, I've just realised that there is JS routing. I was able to use getUri to check if the url contained a string that way, but unable to check for a parameter.

Comment: My guess is that you are hitting the site without the QS, and thus “not authenticated”, and then JS is updating the URL but that’s not getting to the server.